# Error evaluating expression with multiple Database in iReport

Tags: database, jasper-reports, ireport

I need to generate the report using iReport and I am trying to get the data from 2 different databases. I followed this [article](http://www.packtpub.com/article/jasperreports-using-multiple-relational-databases-to-generate-report) by (Bilal Siddiqui, author of JasperReports 3.6 Development Cookbook). But I am getting following error every time. Its working fine individually but when i use sub-report it starts giving me error.

Master Report :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="MasterReport" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="projectName" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\rEPORTS\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="connectionParam" class="java.sql.Connection" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/liferay_6.0.6", "root", "root")]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[QUERY]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="EMAIL" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="32" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[EMAIL]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="126" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Work Station Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="260" y="2" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Work Station Type]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="100" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{EMAIL}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="271" y="0" width="200" height="100"/>
                <subreportParameter name="emailAddress">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{EMAIL}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{connectionParam}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "WorkstationSubReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

**Error filling print... Error evaluating expression :  Source text : java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liferay_6.0.6","root","root")**

**net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :  Source text : java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/liferay_6.0.6","root","root")**

Comment: Did you try report with *iReport*?

Comment: Did you check the connection string with some *MySQL* client or with java code?

Comment: Yes, I am trying this with iReport Designer 4.5.0

Comment: Its running perfectly fine in single report, at the time of sub-report its giving me error.

Comment: I already tried to connect this with MySQL Administrator and its working perfectly fine...

Comment: You should read the full stack trace. I think the problem in classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this steps for testing master report and subreport in *iReport*:

1. Create ***Connection*** in *iReport* and test it. Don't forget to add jar file (*jdbc driver*) to the application (*iReport* in this test case) classpath.
2. Create master report with query. Test it with *iReport* connection.
3. Create subreport with query. Test it with *iReport* connection.
4. Add **Subreport** component to the master report.
5. Set subreport's ***subreportExpression*** and ***subreportParameterExpression*** expressions in master report.
6. Create parameter of ***`java.sql.Connection`*** type in master report. Set ***defaultValueExpression*** for it. Use this parameter in the subreport's ***connectionExpression*** expression of master report.
7. Compile subreport and master report.
8. Test master report via **Preview** button in *iReport*.

The snippet of master report:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ...>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["<some_path>"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="connectionParam" class="java.sql.Connection" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<server_name>:<server_port>/<SID_name>", "<user>", "<password>")]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT id, name FROM main_table]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="259" y="25" width="200" height="100"/>
                <subreportParameter name="masterId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{connectionParam}]]></connectionExpression>

                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "several_connections_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The snippet of subreport:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ...>
    <parameter name="masterId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT details, id FROM details_table where masterId =$P{masterId}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="DETAILS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="50">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="176" y="20" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{masterId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="57" y="17" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DETAILS}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. But I have follow all the steps still its giving me driver not found error. I have created parameter for connection in the master report and set connectionExpression. I also added jar file in classpath in iReport. I am not getting why its giving driver not found error.

Comment: Do you have "MySQL Connection" in *iReport*? Did you try to change the report's language to Java?

Comment: Yes i have mysql connection and another connection of SQLServer for 2nd database

Comment: IMHO, the classpath is the source of your problems

Answer (score 1):

Scorpion,

Solution for this issue is, first you write a query in master report, fetch the records and then define connectionParam with default value expression as

`"java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//<server_name>:<server_port>/<SID_name>", "<user>", "<password>")"`.

In your case, you defined connectionParam first and so you are unable to run master report's query in Ireport.

Thanks,
Srikanth Kattam

Answer (score 1):

Above example does not work in iReport whereas it may work in actual application. 
Problem is iReport does not understand dynamic loading of the database driver automatically even if it is added into ireport classpath and you try to make it as reloadable. So you need to get the established connection from your iReport.

Following is the solution for your problem.

1. Create a connection in iReport to the database by which your subreport will be filled.
2. Say you have given a name "HSQLDB" for your hsql database connection.
3. Now define a connection expression in subreport component section.
4. Use com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.utils.Misc.getConnection("HSQLDB") as a value to it, thats it you are done.

> *com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.utils.Misc.getConnection("HSQLDB")* is the key to success. Remember to remove connection param created in your main report otherwise this will not produce any result.

```
<subreport>
<reportElement uuid="ba5a0c29-332c-4e81-b3b6-71c17d7d2c41" positionType="Float" x="0" y="182" width="364" height="72"/>
<connectionExpression><![CDATA[com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.utils.Misc.getConnection("HSQLDB")]]></connectionExpression>
<subreportExpression><![CDATA["\\\\subreportdir\\subreport_orders.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the langage used by your page. If you use 'Javascript' it fire this error. you should put the langage page to 'Java'